# Does SharePoint need to be installed on the database server?

Tags: 2010, sql-server

Or more specifically, how much of SharePoint needs to be installed on the database server?

I have a SharePoint environment I'm getting ready to move into production but I'm a bit paranoid that the setup isn't quite right. Just fyi, I'm the DBA at my company and I'm not the one who performed the SharePoint install. I was just looking things over before we let the server loose and I noticed that we had running SharePoint services on the SQL Server. This is a multi-farm site with one front end and a database server (not ideal from what I've read but it's all we can do at the moment) so I was curious as to why the database server needed to have SharePoint running on it.

[This technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805948.aspx#InstallSP) seems to indicate that some portion of SharePoint needs to be installed on the all of the farm servers (which I assume includes the database) but our database server has multiple SharePoint services running on it as well as it's own databases in the SQL. We're essentially running two SharePoint sites.

My goal is to remove as much of SharePoint from the SQL server as possible without breaking functionality to the actual site. I've gone in and disabled all of the SharePoint services on the database side and the site still functions perfectly well so it seems like they don't need to be there. Can anyone inform me as to what SharePoint features need to be on the SQL or provide some guidance as to how to go about uninstalling SharePoint without causing any harm to the actual site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharePoint License for Database Server](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/sharepoint-license-for-database-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest answer is: No.

Similar issue (follow first link provided in answer):

[SharePoint License for Database Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/sharepoint-license-for-database-server)

Look also at comment by Jesus Shelby

> The only exception would be if you are running Reporting Service in
>   integration mode, then you would have SharePoint installed alongside
>   the SQL instance hosting the report server.

Comment: Thanks I did see that licensing question as well. I'll read through some of the documents linked there and investigate the Reporting Service point to see if maybe that's why it was installed this way.

Comment: nice catch about Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to install sharepoint on the database server, normal deployments would need 2 servers one for database and the second for the sharepoint components.  And the sharepoint components you can also split them acrsoss servers